# Extract table names from oracle database server

Tags: oracle, dictionary, catalog

I have access to an oracle11g server that blongs to a store and have a software to get reports inside softare but the software is closed source.
bacause i have a username inside database i can access from the software to all reports but i want to automate some works and want to write a python3 script to do that.all i need is that know the table names in DB. i want a code in oracle that returns me the table name.
I have access to database from "PLSQL Developer" and from my notcompleted code in python.

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@serveraddress/dbname')
print (con.version)
cur =con.cursor()
cur.execute(" SOME ORACLE CODE")
#cur.execute('select * from tablesname orderby id' )

for i in cur:
    print (i)
con.close()
```

so what is a code that can execute and return table names to me?

p.s : i even used wireshark to find out what was the code that program sent to server but table names was not there in packet. :(

p.s 2 : any creative and unusual answer is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select table_name
  from user_tables
 order by table_name
```

or

```
select table_name
  from cat
 where table_type = 'TABLE'  
 order by table_name
```

to derive the names of all tables in your current user. Where `cat` is synonym of `user_catalog` data dictionary view and `user_tables` is another data dictionary view automatically created by database during installation.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i ran the code and first time in past days it ended with no error but also it retuned nothing so is any change to code to return table names to me?

Comment: @مهردادمارشگی welcome brother. Are you sure you have any tables in your user ..?

Comment: thanks brother. It seems i have not any but inside PL/SQL Developer program i can see users that have something:CTXSYS , EXFSYS , GENERAL , OLAPSYS , ORDDATA , SRDSYS , SYS , SYSTEM , WMSYS , XDB. So its very kind of you that teach me how can query from this users and wich users are not who i must look for my answer.